# Why Are My Lines Not Rotating? -- CGContextRotateCTM

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, swift2, core-graphics

Here is the code I use to:

- Save the Context
- Move the Context to the middle of rect
- Rotate the Context
- Draw a Line from the rotated Origin
- Restore the Context
- Repeat

  ```
  for i in 1...60 {
      CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
      CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, 0)
      CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, 6 * CGFloat(i))
      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
      CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0)
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
          CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
          CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0, 20)
      }
      else {
          CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0)
          CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0, 15)
      }
      CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
      CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
  }
  ```

The output is several lines, all tightly clumped together.

I am new to Core Graphics, so am I just misunderstanding how this code works? If not, what is the problem?

Regards, Brandon

Comment: You probably have to convert the degrees to radians. before you rotate. Meaning `6 * CGFloat(i) * M_PI / 180` or even shorter `CGFloat(i) * M_PI / 30`

Comment: I just tried that, and it changed the image, but they all still clumped together. (It was something that I needed to do though.)

Comment: A quick note for future questions of this kind: take a screenshot of what your code results in (the clumped lines) and an explanation (clock with "hour"-lines) of what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
for i in 0..<60 {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(Double(i) * M_PI / 30))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 50, 0)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0)
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, -20, 0)
    } else {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, -10, 0)
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

Resulting in

[image]

**Explanation:**

Firstly: the corrected degrees / radians arithmetics.

- `6 * i` is in degrees
- need it in radians - therefore `* M_PI / 180`
- `6 * i * M_PI / 180` can be simplified to `i * M_PI / 30`

Secondly: the correct geometry.

- Translate by x and y in the beginning, centering the clock in its rect
- translate `50` to the right
- draw a line "inwards" `20` or `10` long. Inwards meaning `negative`

Alternative without the inner translate

```
for i in 0..<60 {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(Double(i) * M_PI / 30))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 50, 0)
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 30, 0)
    } else {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 40, 0)
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

**Complete working playground:**

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

class CustomView : UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        for i in 0..<60 {
            CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
            CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(Double(i) * M_PI / 30))
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 50, 0)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0)
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, -20, 0)
            } else {
                CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0)
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, -10, 0)
            }
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
            CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
        }
    }
}

let v = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,200))
v.backgroundColor = .lightGrayColor()
XCPShowView("blabla", view: v)
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Quick question though,  1) why do the negative numbers work? 2) Why / 30?

Comment: @BrandonBradley Was writing the explanation: check again.

Comment: I see, thank you. Again, I'm still new to custom graphics, but, why did you translate 50 to the right?

Comment: @BrandonBradley that is *your* width of the clock. Choose the width of your clock here or refactor it to be a parameter or constant somewhere outside the drawing code. You basically have to think a little bit more about the code, plug it into the playground and play around with the values and you will quickly understand the meaning of them.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.